Не выполняется кнопка в телеграм боте на Python. pyTelegramBotAPI
     import telebot
     import webbrowser
     import requests
     import json
     from telebot import types

     bot = telebot.TeleBot('6352534163:AAE3ILv51Gzq69rxHTmamr1djKwjQEVF7Vg')
     API = '016585da38d92daa122ec334ee3e1ffd'
     yan = 13

     @bot.message_handler(commands=['site', 'website'])
     def site(message):
         webbrowser.open('https://www.poizon.com')

     @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
     def main(message):

         file = open('./photo.png','rb')
         bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,file)

         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<b>Привет</b>✋{message.from_user.first_name}. Я          бот, который сориентирует тебя по цене товара и доставки именно в твой город.(<em>я считаю без          учета посредниов, лишь стоимость товара и доставки до определенного города</em>).Для начала          напиши, какой у тебя индекс?',parse_mode='html')

     @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
     def text(message):
         markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
         item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Рассчитать в ручную✅', callback_data='manual')
         item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Рассчитать через ссылку❌', callback_data='automatic')
         item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад⬅️', callback_data='back')
         markup.add(item,item1,item2)
         city = message.text.strip().lower()
         res = requests.get(f'https://postprice.ru/engine/russia/api.php?from={city}&to=630008&mass=40&valuation=500&vat=1')
         data = json.loads(res.text)
         bot.reply_to(message, f'ваш город: {data["city_from"]}', reply_markup=markup)

     @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
     def callback(call):
         if call.message:
             if call.data == 'manual':
                 markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                 item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кроссовки',callback_data='sneakers')
                 item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Куртки', callback_data='jackets')
                 item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сумки', callback_data='bags')
                 item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Легкая одежда', callback_data='clothes')
                 item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Аксессуары', callback_data='accessories')
                 item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Штаны', callback_data='pants')
                 item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кофты', callback_data='sweatshirts')
                 markup1.add(item,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6)
                 bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери категорию товара',reply_markup=markup1)

     @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
     def callback1(call1):
         if call1.message:
             if call1.data == 'sneakers':
                 bot.send_message(call1.message.chat.id, 'Напишите цену в юанях')


     @bot.message_handler(content_types['photo','video','audio','sticker','document','voice','location','video_note','preview','contact','folder'])
     def get_file(message):
         bot.reply_to(message,'Извини я не понимаю что ты хочешь')

         bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Хочу сделать 2-х уровневые инлайн кнопки в Тг боте. При выборе категории товара бот должен отправлять сообщение, но этого не происходит, и среда разработки тоже никак не реагирует. В чем может быть проблема?
